# Cannot find the connection created in power query in pivot table connection

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I created a connection appending two tables from power query. Now, I want to update my existing pivot table with the connection. But, I cannot find the option in the "Change data source". But, if I check it in the connections options in the data tab, then, I can see the connection I created. Please help!!!

Comment: Does your connection show up when you click on *Change data source* and do:

**1.** *Use an external data source*
**2.** *Choose connection...*
**3.** *Connections in this Workbook*, (the connection should be under this section)

Comment: Nope, but I could see it in the Connections option in the Data tab though

Answer (score 0):

If the Pivot table is based on the Data Model, then the "Change Data Source" button will be greyed out, because the data source for the Pivot table is the Data Model.

If you have appended two queries, it may well be that all you need to do is refresh the pivot table.

In the following scenario, the first screenshot shows the pivot table when only the table on the left has been loaded to the data model.

[image]

In the next picture, the table on the right has been added as a query and saved as a connection. Then the table has been appended with the existing "myQuery". Then the Pivot table has been refreshed and the numbers show that it includes the new data values.

[image]

If you want to change the data source for the pivot table when it is sourced from the Data Model, you need to work in the PivotTable Fields panel and select the table or query that you want to use. In the screenshot below, you can see that the pivot table uses fields from myQuery, but I could also select fields from Table1 and Table2, which are the original tables in the grid.

[image]

Comment: Hey Teylyn, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the reason I was trying to append the queries or table is because my data exceeds 1M records and I want to keep it on Excel itself and thus, i have multiple sheets in the same excel file which do not have any relationship. So, when I just created a New Connection appending two queries representing one table each, it worked but when I added it to my datamodel, it did not let show as a connection in "Change Data Source" option and thus, I recreated the entire dashboard altogether.